# bootstrap-icons change fonts path static site

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-5

I want to change the **@font-face** src path in **bootstrap-icons** because it's not displayed in my **index.html**

I'm using sass and laravel-mix to compile to css.

**here is my src/sass/app.scss file:**

```
@import "~bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons";
```

**here is my index.html file:**

```
<i class="bi bi-archive-fill"></i>
```

**here is my file structure :**

```
my-app/
├── dist/
│   ├── assets/
│   │    ├── css/
│   │    │    ├── app.css
│   ├── fonts/
│   │    ├── vendor/
│   │    │    ├── bootstrap-icons/
│── src/sass/
│    ├── app.scss
├── index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the @font-face rule like this:

```
@import "~bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons";

@font-face {
  font-family: "bootstrap-icons";
  src:  url("../../fonts/vendor/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.woff2?856008caa5eb66df68595e734e59580d") format("woff2"),
        url("../../fonts/vendor/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.woff?856008caa5eb66df68595e734e59580d") format("woff");
}
```

I had a similar problem and this worked for me :)